# VHDL increase decrease integer value

Tags: vhdl

I have create project witch has an "counter" counter = Integer. I need to increase/decrease an integer value by pressing the buttons. the progress has 2 entitys, entity 1 should increase
the value and  entity 2 should decrease the value, Im not allow to do so with component how to do this?

```
-- component 1 -------------------------------
entity MyCounter is
 port(
    clock: in std_logic;
    KEY: in std_logic;
    counter: in integer range 0 to 15;
    clk_out: out std_logic
  );
end MyCounter; 

architecture arch of MyCounter is

component decrease
    port(

    clock: in std_logic;
    KEY: in std_logic;
    counter: in integer range 0 to 15;
    clk_out: out std_logic

        );
end component;

begin
    p1: process(clock, KEY)
     variable counter : integer;
       begin
         if KEY = '1' then
          counter <= counter + 1;
         end if;
end process; 

end arch;


-- component 2 -------------------------------
entity decrease is
 port(
    clock: in std_logic;
    KEY: in std_logic;
    counter: in integer range 0 to 15;
    clk_out: out std_logic
  );
end decrease ; 

architecture arch of decrease is
begin

    p1: process(clock, KEY)
     begin
      if KEY = '1' then
        counter <= counter - 1;
    end if;
end process; 

end arch;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile, you can't use `<=` to assign to a variable.  Nor can you assign to an input (which `counter` is defined as...)

You also can't have two separate processes writing to the same signal (when it's of a non-resolved type, like `integer`).  Is this an academic exercise?  Why not just have a single process which does:

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
  if up = '1' then
     count <= count + 1;
  elsif down = '1' then 
     count <= count - 1;
  end if;
end if;
```

As you have a limited range counter, you'll have to be explicit about making it wrap around (or saturate) when you try and increment it or decrement it beyond the acceptable range.  The simulator will die otherwise.  The synthesis tool may or may not do what you require, depending - but it's better to be explicit with that sort of behaviour.

Also, [get rid of `std_logic_arith`](http://parallelpoints.com/numbers-in-vhdl/) - if you want vectors to be treated as numbers, `use ieee.numeric_std.all` instead

Comment: thank you for the input but I need to change the value form an separate architecture. not else statement

Comment: Sorry, not possible (directly anyway - unless I'm missing a trick!) - can you describe what you are trying to achieve?  Why must you use two architectures?

Answer (score 1):

Variables are local inside process, so You can't use variables in this case. Use signal instead.

Also don't use std_logic_arith. Use numeric_std instead.